# Failed to resolve: com.airbnb.android:lottie:lottieVersion Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

Tags: android

```
// Lottie animations
implementation("com.airbnb.android:lottie:lottieVersion:6.1.0")
```

Failed to resolve: com.airbnb.android:lottie:lottieVersion
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

What I do on this error

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an issue with the repository name.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.airbnb.android/lottie
implementation('com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.1.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `com.airbnb.android:lottie:{insert_version}` (see [their documentation](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)). So in your case:

```
implementation('com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.1.0')
```